# angular.io bootstrap integration

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-cli

I am no longer able to apply twitter bootstrap via .angular-cli.json to a vanilla angular build generated by the angular cli. This used to work just fine, but after upgrading to the latest version of node and angular cli and git bash, I am no longer able to do so.

Incidentally, any changes I make to the styles.css in the src directory are not being applied either. Have I overlooked anything, perhaps?

**Tech Details** 
os: Windows 10 
node: v6.11.2 
@angular/cli: 1.2.7 
git: 2.13.3 
bootstrap: ^3.3.7

**Steps**

Using git bash 
 1. ng new abc 
 2. cd abc 
 3. npm install --save bootstrap 
 4. edit styles in .angular-cli.json 
 `"styles": ["../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "styles.css"]`
 5. ng serve 
 6. navigate to http://localhost:4200

**Angular cli message** 
`WARNING in C:/Users/fisk/Documents/code/abc/~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find source file 'compiler.es5.ts': Error: Can't resolve './compiler.es5.ts' in 'C:\Users\fisk\Documents\                                 code\abc\node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular'
 @ C:/Users/fisk/Documents/code/abc/~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.es5.js 7:0-72
 @ C:/Users/fisk/Documents/code/abc/src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
 webpack: Compiled with warnings.`

**Screenshot Link** 
No styles being applied 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dtuj.png

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console ?

Comment: MIne is working fine. I don't know what problem you are facing

Comment: No errors, just a warning, but the page displays on port 4200.

Comment: You probaby need to update your @angular/cli and node version to the latest version. I have tried this and everything is working fine.

Comment: I have the latest node LTS version and the most recent angular cli version.

Comment: I would say the opposite, you should probably downgrade your @angular/cli version. Does it work without the bootstrap package installed?

Comment: Yes, it works without the bootstrap package. Everything seems to be in order and the page displays, except that bootstrap styles are not being applied and any changes to styles.css under folder src have no effect.

Comment: I just did the installation myself following the exact steps you mentioned and it was working. Just saying the possibility might be with the angular/cli and node version you have.I don't think the information you have provided has any problem in it.

Comment: One approach would be removing node_modules folder and running npm install again. If you've updated your node and @angular/cl versions after the packages were already installed, that could be the cause of this problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it's a completely fresh build. The generation and install processes were done using the upgraded versions.

Comment: I've done some additional tests and at the moment I believe it to be related to git bash. If I run the installation steps using cmd (command prompt) it works perfectly fine. However, when the build is generated via git bash, global styles and any css imports specified in angular-cli.json do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you for all the replies and suggestions.

**In short**

- Styles.css and bootstrap styles are imported correctly if the angular project was generated via cmd prompt
- Styles.css and the bootstrap styles have no effect if the angular project was generated using git bash, which is what I was using.

I was able to replicate the same symptoms on two separate machines, Windows 10 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Please do these steps:
    npm install bootstrap-sass ng2-bootstrap --save
    Update The angular cli json file
    "styles": [
        "style.scss",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss
    ],

Comment: Thank you, but no luck and exactly the same symptoms with ng2-bootstrap (ngx-bootstrap) https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap

Comment: yeah, I can see now it was renamed to ngxbootstrap.  But it is working well for me.  can you share more details like screenshot?

Comment: Sure, added a link to a screenshot in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

angular uses webpack. add your css in the style section of webpack.config.js. there may be a src/style.css file in which you can import it too.